# SQL: Difference between two count query

Tags: sql

I work on a sql problem on this [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-4). In short, you have one table named `station`. in this table, the schema is:

```
id: int
city: varchar(21)
```

city column can be duplicated. The question is: difference between total cities (with duplication) and total cities without duplication. here is my code:

```
select
 (select count(*) from station) - 
 (select count(*) from (select city from station group by city) as c);
```

In short, I use two query: one is sum all and one is sum with `group by` city and then count again on that query. (little complicated). Here is the answer:

```
select count(city)- count(distinct city) from station;
```

My question is: at second query, how many query will database really execute. Is only one or two queries as my code. If there are two queries, which condition can we write same query in same `FROM` clause?

Comment: You have to ask the DB developer to know what they do internally. But they will not run 2 "queries"

Comment: @juergend is that really related to db mechanism. I think this is something related to "synatic sugar" query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sub queries involved and aggregation is done on filtered rows.

So to answer you question : there's only one query.